# Search Client for Elastic Search Search in Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I 'm trying to write a plugin for Elastic Search which would execute a simple query against the elastic search and retrieve the results. Here is the error I got. Can any one help me?

```
This  is the error :
{"error":"BindTransportException[Failed to bind to [9300-9400]]; nested: IllegalStateException[await*() in I/O thread causes a dead lock or sudden performance drop. Use addListener() instead or call await*() from a different thread.]; ","status":
```

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: Google "Elastic Search plugin api" and "elasticsearch plugin tutorial"

Comment: This is not a plugin related question. It's related to the Elasticsearch Client API. @user4654, you'll need to rewrite your question telling us what you are doing, how you are doing it along with error message. We are not fortune tellers here.